# Can't verify an app on ios

Tags: ios, ipa, verify

So I installed a modified Spotify app on my iPad Air 2n, iPhone 6.

After I downloaded it I had to trust the developer, everything was fine, it worked and I could open the app. But after some time I had to verify the app again.

Quoted for the apple support page I got this:

> After you verify an app for the first time, your iPhone, iPad, or iPod
>   touch must reverify the app developer's certificate periodically to
>   maintain trust.

Ok that isn't that strange, so I try to verify the app again, but now when I click on `Verify App` **he won't do it**.

Example picture from the support site is exactly how it looks before and after I click on `Verify App`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You were either facing the following issue or the https://ppq.apple.com was temporarily down.

> You must be connected to the Internet to verify the app developer's
>   certificate when establishing trust. If you're behind a firewall, make
>   sure that it's configured to allow connections to
>   https://ppq.apple.com. If you aren't connected to the Internet when
>   you trust an app, the device displays "Not Verified" instead. To use
>   the app, connect to the Internet and tap the Verify App button.